# Angular2: AsyncPipe and Observable, can't retrieve property (TypeError: Cannot read property ... of null)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular, observable

I try to retrieve property of object that is returned by Observable

However I see some examples in answers at SO, in my app I get error. The same error is reproduced in Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X5xNDOFmCpLOnzv4X0xo?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [AppService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `<h1>.?</h1>
    <div *ngIf = "data$">
      {{(data$ | async)?.total}}
    </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  data$ : Observable<any> = null;

  constructor (private appservice : AppService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.data$ = this.appservice.getData();
 }
}
```

As it advised I use safe navigator operator (?.), but it doesn't help.

Comment: As far as I remember they introduced a bug in RC.5 (should be fixed already) https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10639

Answer (score 2):

RC.5 introduce a bug https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10639 therefore this is currently not working.

As a workaround you need to subscribe in code and assign to a property like

```
this.appservice.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

and then bind to `data`

Comment: ok, this way I know, but I want to understand how it can work with ?. operator.

Comment: I mentioned that in my comment above. It's currently not working. I updated my answer.

Comment: When they deploy this fix, could you update your answer?

Comment: Can you remind me? ;-) I posted a few thousand Angular2 answers already and that's a bit hard to track. I'm pretty sure it will be included in the next update and then this question and answer becomes obsolete anyway.